ggplot2 - multiple geoms, filtered data, weird x-axis placement
I'm trying to understand ggplot2 outputs when layering geoms and filtered data, specifically with geom_bar and geom_col. When using multiple geoms of the same type, one with full data and one with filtered data, I get different results depending on the approach.
Synthetic data:
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  locations = letters[1:20],
  scores = sample(50:99,20)
  )

The following example creates two layers: 1) one with the original data faded out in grey and 2) filtered data focusing on two groups colored orange. What I expect is for the groups to have similar placements on the x-axis e.g. location a is placed in same spot on x-axis, same for location e. The first faded layer is fine, but the second layer puts location a and e next to each other in different spots than the original layer.
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df, aes(x = locations, y = scores), stat = "identity", fill = "#cccccc") +
  geom_bar(data = filter(df, locations %in% c("a","e")), aes(x = locations, y = scores), stat = "identity", fill = "#d55c19")

This example for some reason works. Instead of two layers I use 3: 1) original, 2) location a, and 3) location e. All the locations are placed correctly on the x-axis.
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df, aes(x = locations, y = scores), stat = "identity", fill = "#cccccc") +
  geom_bar(data = filter(df, locations %in% c("a")), aes(x = locations, y = scores), stat = "identity", fill = "#d55c19") +
  geom_bar(data = filter(df, locations %in% c("e")), aes(x = locations, y = scores), stat = "identity", fill = "#d55c19")

How is it the first example does not work but the second one does? In addition, this seems to only happen with geom_bar/geom_col and not geom_point or geom_line.

The bars are centered on 'a' and 'e', they are just much wider. Use width = 0.9 to fix that. geom_point and geom_line don't have widths, so it doesn't happen. The width gets set to the resolution of the data (see ?resolution) which is the distance between the two bars. In your last example, the resolution defaults to 1, since there is only 1 bar per layer.

I actually think this is a bug, since on a discrete x-axis this should not be happening, the resolution should always be 1, as ?resolution mentions.

The first example is not putting a and e next to each other. Rather its setting a width for the bars that is wider then the first layer. Here is the same example, but with the width = 1:
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df, aes(x = locations, y = scores),
 stat = "identity", fill = "#cccccc") +
  geom_bar(data = filter(df, locations %in% c("a","e")),
 aes(x = locations, y = scores),
 stat = "identity", fill = "#d55c19", width = 1)


Here is an alternative approach to controlling the fill of specific bars, without stacking multiple layers.
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = locations, y = scores, fill = locations %in% c('a','e'))) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#cccccc", "#d55c19")) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')


Created on 2024-05-24 with reprex v2.1.0

I think if I had taken the time to read the internals of geom_bar/geom_col, I would have figured out to set width to not 1 but 0.9. Per tidyverse:
"By default, the width of bars is 0.9 (90% of the resolution of the data). You can set this argument to a lower value to get bars that are narrower with more space between them."
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/faq-bars.html#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20the%20width%20of,the%20resolution%20of%20the%20data).
